# c++ copying constructor for a composition class

Tags: c++, constructor, composition

I'm learning a c++ tutorial and having a hard time understanding part of the following code(see the commented part):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    A(A&src)
    {
        cout<<"copying A..."<<endl;
    }
    A(void){}
    void Do(void)
    {
        cout<<"A is doing something"<<endl;
    }
};

class B
{
public:
    B(B&src)
    {
        cout<<"copying B..."<<endl;
    }
    B(void){}
    void Do(void)
    {
        cout<<"B is doing something"<<endl;
    }
};

class Compo
{
public:
    Compo(Compo &src):f1(f1),f2(f2)//???

    {
        cout<<"Copying Compo..."<<endl;
    }
    Compo(void){}
    A f1;
    B f2;

};

int main(void)
{
    Compo co1;
    Compo co2=co1;
    co2.f1.Do();
    co2.f2.Do();
}
```

So how does the compiler know which f1/f2 belongs to which Compo? Is there a way to make it more explicit?

thanks for the help

Comment: Copy constructors take a `const` reference : `B(const B& src)`

Comment: You're not doing it right. It should be `f1(src.f1)` etc. If you invest in a slightly more intelligent compiler, you should be able to get a warning.

Comment: @KerrekSB isn't the problem that only one version of f1 even exists (there is no argument called f1 or f2 just the member)

Comment: @aaronman: I'm not sure what you mean. There isn't any ambiguity here about which name names which object. It's just the wrong object.

Comment: @KerrekSB exactly, there's no ambiguity because he's just setting the member equal to itself, which obviously does nothing

Comment: @aaronman I disagree. "obviously does nothing" - it's undefined behavior. It could crash.

Comment: @aaronman: It's arguably undefined behaviour, because of lvalue-to-rvalue nonsense etc.

Comment: I would say that it is most likely to do nothing

Comment: @aaronman: please stop kidding with UB. Mundane errors like that cause real-life crashes, or can do way worse. It's not likely to do nothing, and even if it did, quite irrelevant.

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't, you're initializing `f1` with itself, which can't lead to anything good. You want:

```
Compo(const Compo &src):f1(src.f1),f2(src.f2)//???
{
    cout<<"Copying Compo..."<<endl;
}
```

Another good example to **turn on warnings**. If you already have them on, pay attention to them.